# Processing: sprite movement stops randomly

Tags: processing

I'm new to processing and have been modifying someone's code. I understand all of it besides why my sprite keeps stopping randomly. I end up losing movement all together at what seems to be random points. Any help?

```java
PImage img;
sprite player;
wall[] walls; 

void setup() {

  size(750, 750);
  img = loadImage("sprite.png");
  player = new sprite(50,300);
  frameRate(60);
  smooth();

  walls = new wall[3];
  walls[0] = new wall(250,0,40,500);
  walls[1] = new wall(500,250,40,500);
  walls[2] = new wall(300,200,40,500);

} 
void draw() {

  background(255, 255, 255); 
  noStroke(); 

  player.draw();
  player.move(walls);

  for(int i = 0; i < walls.length; i++){
    walls[i].draw();
  }

}

class sprite {

  float x;
  float y;

  sprite(float _x, float _y){
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
  }

  void draw(){
    image(img,x,y);
  }

  void move(wall[] walls){

    float possibleX = x;
    float possibleY = y;

    if (keyPressed==true) {

      println(key);

      if (key=='a') { 
        possibleX= possibleX - 2;
      } 
      if (key=='d') { 
        possibleX = possibleX + 2;
      } 
      if (key=='w') { 
        possibleY = possibleY - 2;
      } 
      if (key=='s') { 
        possibleY = possibleY + 2;
      }
    }

    boolean didCollide = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < walls.length; i++){
      if(possibleX > walls[i].x && possibleX < (walls[i].x + walls[i].w) && possibleY > walls[i].y && possibleY < walls[i].y + walls[i].h){
        didCollide = true;
      }
    }

    if(didCollide == false){
      x = possibleX;
      y = possibleY;
    }

  }

}

class wall {

  float x;
  float y;
  float w;
  float h;

  wall(float _x, float _y, float _w, float _h){
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
    w = _w;
    h = _h;
  }


  void draw(){
    fill(0);
    rect(x,y,w,h);
  }

}
```

Comment: You'll have better luck if you narrow your problem down to a [mcve]. Note that this should not be your entire sketch. For example, your problem has nothing to do with drawing the images, so you don't need that. Just narrow it down to a single hard-coded rectangle colliding with another hard-coded rectangle. Have you tried [debugging](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) your code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your `move()` function:

```java
void move(wall [] walls) {
    ...
    boolean didCollide = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < walls.length; i++) {
        if (possibleX > walls[i].x && possibleX < (walls[i].x + walls[i].w) && ...){
             didCollide = true;
        }
    }

    if (didCollide == false) {
      x = possibleX;
      y = possibleY;
    }

}
```

You check for collisions, in that for loop, which is good! However, you never resolve the collision (i.e. move the person Sprite away from the wall so that the wall is no longer within its possible rectangle), so the person can no longer move because each time this function gets called, didCollide ends up being true still.

You can test this next time by adding this code:

```java
if (didCollide == false) {
    ...
} else {
    println("I stopped moving.");
    // could also put collision-resolving code here 
}
```

If you see that in the console, it means you hit a wall.

Resolving the collision is a matter of moving the sprite the distance between it and the wall's nearest edge away from the wall, plus a little more so that you're not touching it still, like this:

```java
// If sprite to the left of the wall, i.e. went too far to the right...
float diff = walls[i].x - walls[i].w - this.x;
this.x += diff + 1.0
...
// If sprite below the wall, and essentially too high up....
float diff = walls[i].y + wall[i].h - this.y;
this.y += diff + 1.0
```